# Background moving with overflow hidden

Tags: css, magnific-popup

While working on a website I encountered the following problem. Magnific Popup (lightbox plugin) sets the HTML to overflow: hidden; while the lightbox is open, this prevents scrolling.

On my page I have a fixed header image:

```
.header {
background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1920x400");
height: 400px;
background-size: contain;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

When I open the lightbox the html is set to overflow: hidden; **and the background image moves.** Overflow: hidden; is causing the background to move.

I have no idea what casuses this behavior, I have tried the following things:

- Magnific Popup also sets a margin-right on the html element to prevent the content from shifting, this doesnt work with the background.
- Have tried setting overflow-y: scroll; while the lightbox is open, this also does not work.
- Using background-origin or background-clip also doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I simplified my code and ended up with this Codepen, to see the background moving click the button.

**Codepen:** [Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/Aralon/pen/jPNrdZ/)

Hope you will be able to help me,

Wouter

**Edit:**

I would like to solve the moving background without setting the overflow to auto. I don't like it when the scrollbar is visible when the lightbox is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to this problem, this was posted in the css reddit:

1. `background-size: calc(100% - 17px)`
   This is the first solution [Codepen of first solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdWmpx)
2. `background-size: 100vw`
   This is the second solution [Codepen of second solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVLmOG)

Answer (score 6):

From MDN article for [`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment):

> **fixed:**  This keyword means that the background is fixed with regard to the **viewport**.

Because your element is positioned in relation to the "viewport", when you switch to `overflow: hidden`, the viewport gets slightly wider with the removal of the scrollbar, causing a repositioning of the background due to your use of `background-size: contain`.  The background now has slightly more space to cover and therefore increases in size slightly.

As much as I hate to use `!important`, you can override the plugin's changes:

```
html{
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```

If the plugin uses a class instead of directly altering the html element's style, you can override it without important.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would there be any other solution to fix the moving background without setting the overflow to auto? I would like to keep the scrollbar hidden.

Comment: @Aralon I can't think of a clean way to handle it without removing `background-attachment: fixed` or `background-size: cover`.  You might be able to wrap your entire page in a div, then use `background-attachment: scroll` and set the scrollbars on the `div` instead.  But that gets messy quick.

Comment: Yes, that would get very messy, but I'll give it a try :) Maybe a jquery plugin like backstretch or anystretch could solve the problem? but the last time I tried that they didn't work very well with background-attachment: fixed.

Comment: If you're willing to use javascript for this then your best bet would probably be to get rid of `background-attachment: fixed` and simulate it yourself.  It shouldn't be too hard, you would just update the `background-position` on scroll and resize.

Comment: Also note though, if that `17px` margin added is a fixed `17px`, it may not match every browser's scrollbar perfectly, so your header will resized, if even just slightly.  So maybe keep `fixed` but simluate `contain` with js.

Comment: Found a solution to this problem without removing the overflow: hidden. Check out the answer below.

Comment: @aralon Nice.  Not quite the same as `contain` in all cases I don't think (could be wrong), but if it works in your case, that's much cleaner than js.